# What is the lifetime of a SOAP v2 session in magento?

Tags: soap

I was wondering what the lifetime is of a soap v2 session in Magento.

I wish to implement an auto-renew method every x minutes but for that, I need to know how long a login session/token stays valid.

Is it 5, 10, 15 60 minutes?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be able to change this in 'System' -> 'Configuration' -> 'Magento Core API'. The default is 3600 seconds (1 hour).

[image: This is what it looks like in EE 1.13]